# Is it possible to configure QuickFIX to server from one port for multiple session?

Tags: quickfix

I have a FIX server implemented using QuickFIX. I create FIX sessions for each client currently.So, there's a 1-1 relation between Sessions and Connections. Is it possible to serve for all clients from a particular port? I mean 1-Many relation between Connection and Sessions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but make sure you have failover ports/hosts in your config. There maybe scenarios when one port can get overwhelmed, so you can seamlessly swap over to a different port.

Sessions only need your `beginString`, `senderCompID`, `targetCompID` and `sessionQualifier`. So if you have an unique session(s) it willn't matter if all connect to the same port.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "FIX sessions for each client". That sounds to me like you serve different clients according to different sessions. But if all sessions are bound to a particular port then all clients will receive all the messages written on the port. It's therefore insecure because one client sees another client's messages. Right?

I am not sure why you'd need more than one session to bind to a particular port. What's the reason?